# Shadows put white lines around div's

Tags: css

So I have been trying to make a simple page with simple dropshadows.  The problem comes when I add a couple of tabs to the box that has a drowshadow.  I have placed a copy of the html and css at http://blah.eu5.org/test/.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong as I know I have seen it done properly using css before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white lines are actually `silver` lines, so you need this:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

instead of

```
box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 silver, 1px 1px 0 silver, 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

and it will be fine

Comment: This is perfect.  I obviously need to read more about shadows!